# T-SQL: Create column that looks up and calculates based on a previous value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for writing a query that returns a calculated value that uses a lookup to find a previous value.  For example, I have two tables, as shown below.  I have joined them together in a view, but I need to add an additional column that gives me a previous value:

CEO_Table:

```
CEO_Name      | FromDate   | ToDate       
-----------------------------------------
Glen Bryant   | 2000-11-30 | 2002-06-30
Bob Costa     | 2002-6-30  | 2004-9-15  
Gill Bogart   | 2004-9-15  | 2009-10-01  
Ben Olson     | 2009-10-01 | 2010-08-10
```

Expense_Table:

```
Date       | AsOf_Expenses_Total_Millions (as Exp)
-----------------------------------------
2001-01-01 | 100
2002-01-01 | 300
2003-01-01 | 155
2004-01-01 | 350
2005-01-01 | 400
2006-01-01 | 600
2007-01-01 | 150
2008-01-01 | 200
2009-01-01 | 300
2010-01-01 | 500
```

I am attempting to use these two tables to construct a view that adds on 3 additional columns: 
CEO (looks up the CEO for the given date); 
LastCEOExp (looks up the previous CEO's last expense value);
PercentChange (uses the LastCEOExp to calculate the percent change, using a formula (Exp - LastCEOExp)/(LastCEOExp) * 100)

CEO_Expenses_Change_Over_Time:

```
Date       | Exp | CEO_Name      | LastCEOExp | PercentChange
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2001-01-01 | 100 | Glenn Bryant  | NULL       | NULL
2002-01-01 | 300 | Glenn Bryant  | NULL       | NULL
2003-01-01 | 155 | Bob Costa     | 300        | -48%
2004-01-01 | 350 | Bob Costa     | 300        | 16%
2005-01-01 | 400 | Gill Bogart   | 350        | 14%
2006-01-01 | 600 | Gill Bogart   | 350        | 71%
2007-01-01 | 150 | Gill Bogart   | 350        | -57%
2008-01-01 | 200 | Gill Bogart   | 350        | -42%
2009-01-01 | 300 | Gill Bogart   | 350        | -14%
2010-01-01 | 500 | Ben Olson     | 300        | 66%
```

I have gotten so far as to adding the CEO_Name column, but am having trouble with the LastCEOExp column.  Once I have that column nailed down, I can put together the PercentChange column on my own.  Anyone have any advice?  I am guessing that I could use a CTE for this task, but am unsure of where to start.  Below is what I have:

```
SELECT exp.[Date]
  ,exp.[Exp]
  ,ceo.[CEO_Name]
FROM [Expense_Table] exp
INNER JOIN [CEO_Table] ceo
ON exp.[Date] between ceo.[FromDate] and ceo.[ToDate]
```

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive on both sides. You will need to use `ON ceo.FromDate <= exp.[Date] AND exp.[Date] < ceo.[ToDate]` instead to avoid overlaps.

Comment: What datatype are your *Date* fields? **date**? **datetime**? or perhaps **smalldatetime**?  The perticulare way overlaps are avoided will vary on the particular column type.

Comment: Thanks, I am noticing the double rows on each CEO transition, will update the BETWEEN clause.  I am using DATE data type

Comment: @datamedici - how many rows do the tables have ?

Comment: Not too many, performance won't be an issue, so I could use a nested select statement in my select clause if needed. The expense table has 193 rows, whereas the CEO table has 18. The eventual view should have 193

Comment: @datamedici - also, is this something from a textbook or a real company's database ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Real organization, although the data has been altered for confidentiality purposes, the logic of the model and objects are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get yourself familiar with [window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms189461.aspx) in SQL Server. Here's a solution:

```
WITH
    tmp AS
    (
        SELECT      exp.Date,
                    CEO_Name,
                    exp.Exp,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ceo.FromDate)       AS CEOOrder,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ceo.CEO_Name ORDER BY exp.Date DESC)
                                                                    AS ExpOrder
        FROM        CEO_Table       ceo
        INNER JOIN  Expense_Table   exp     ON exp.Date BETWEEN ceo.FromDate AND ceo.ToDate
    )

SELECT      t1.Date,
            t1.CEO_Name,
            t1.Exp,
            t2.Exp                              AS LastCEOExp,
            (t1.Exp - t2.Exp) / t2.Exp * 100    AS PercentChange
FROM        tmp     t1
LEFT JOIN   tmp     t2  ON t1.CEOOrder = t2.CEOOrder + 1  -- This select the last CEO
                       AND t2.ExpOrder = 1                -- This select his last pay
ORDER BY    t1.CEOOrder, t1.ExpOrder DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f565c/1)

Answer (score 0):

I did code like this and I use

ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

in your case ROW_NUMBER can be over time and then you play with the  ROW_ID
you can create function return TABLE  SHIFT+1 ROW_ID  then JOIN the tables, be careful you need to add index for large sets on ROW_ID when you use temp table, views...

second option you create function (parameter datetime) return the value will work for small sets

```
SELECT A.*,PrevYear.*, cast(( ROUND((cast(A.[Exp] as float) - cast(PrevYear.[Exp] as float) ) / cast(A.[Exp] as float) * 100  ,2) ) as varchar) + '%' as  PercentChange from
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY exp.[Date] DESC) AS Row, exp.[Date]
  ,exp.[AsOf_Expenses_Total_Millions] as [Exp]
  ,ceo.[CEO_Name]
FROM [Expense_Table] exp
INNER JOIN [CEO_Table] ceo
ON exp.[Date] between ceo.[FromDate] and ceo.[ToDate]
) A left join


(SELECT (ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY exp.[Date] DESC) -1) AS Row, exp.[Date]
  ,exp.[AsOf_Expenses_Total_Millions] as [Exp]
  ,ceo.[CEO_Name] as PrevCEO_Name
FROM [Expense_Table] exp
INNER JOIN [CEO_Table] ceo
ON exp.[Date] between ceo.[FromDate] and ceo.[ToDate]
) PrevYear

on A.row = PrevYear.row
order by A.row
```

Answer (score -1):

I think lead/lag might get you what you are looking for:

if object_id(N'tempdb..##lag_table', N'U') is not null

  drop table ##lag_table;

go

create table ##lag_table (

  [id]         [int] identity(1, 1)

  , [model]    [sysname]

  , [residual] [decimal] (9, 2)

  , [created]  [date]

  );

go

insert into ##lag_table

            ([model],[residual],[created])

values      (N'modelA',10,N'2013-01-01'),

            (N'modelA',5,N'2011-01-01'),

            (N'modelA',2,N'2009-01-01');

go

--

-- code block end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

--

-- code block begin

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- 

--  Select a prior value based on a stated interval or count 

select [id]

       , [model]

       , [residual]

       , lead([residual], 1.0)

           over (

             partition by [model]

             order by [created] desc) as [lead]

       , lag([residual], 1.0)

           over (

             partition by [model]

             order by [created] desc) as [lag]

from   ##lag_table;

Comment: Your answer isn't relevant to the question